# Eliminar dendograma en HeatMap R

Tags: r

tengo el siguiente código en R para en base a un vector de longitud 400 con valores de 0 a 1 crear un heatmap en el cual se pueden distinguir formas.

```
display_pattern <- function(x){
  x <- unlist(x)
  mat <- matrix(x, 20, byrow=T)
  heatmap(mat, Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE)
}
```

Pero a la hora de aplicar la función con un ejemplo, como podría ser el siguiente, es como si el Rowv y el Colv no funcionasen.

```
display_pattern(patterns[257,1:400])
```

He probado a hacer el código fuera de la función, y lo que sale es lo esperado, que es esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero me sale esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podría solucionarlo? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En este caso, tienes que cambiar un detalle en la función `heatmap`, en vez de colocar los parametros `Rowv` y `Colv` es igual `FALSE`, estos deben ser `NA`. Tal como la función a continuación:

```
heatmap(mat, Rowv=NA, Colv=NA)
```